# Rails 4 increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model and it has a views attribute.

I want to increment views by 1 each time their profile is viewed.

The views attribute is defaulted to 0 in the db.

Now the problem I am having is the following:

- First time profile is viewed
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @user.increment!(:views)
  This will set views equal to 1.
- Second time profile is viewed views is updated to 3.

It seems at random times views is updated by 2 and not 1.

Comment: are you sure you arent accidentally calling increment in other actions?

Comment: What happens the third and fourth time? Is the behavior predictable or seemingly random?

Comment: Hi, the behavior actually seems to be random.

Comment: Believe I figured out the problem. I have a search where I view profiles. I made the div clickable with javascript using: window.location = "". I changed it to: window.location.replace() and it seems to work.

Comment: :) okay. glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good/safe way to maintain profile views. If there are many people viewing you could have race conditions.

There is a highly sophisticated gem called 'impressionist'. (https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist). Use it. You will have access to lot of features like getting unique profile views based on User, or IP, or session hash etc.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but I'm not able to get it working. I need to record unique impressions for my "profile" action only for certain sessions and update the views column. I've added impressionist :actions => [:profile] to my controller and is_impressionable :counter_cache => { :column_name => :views } to my model. Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Seems impressionist is incrementing by 2 as well